# Do small-scale physical effects lead to larger systems being required for long life (of dynamic systems, not static objects)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I think physicists can deal with this question best.

I answered a question about "immortality" when some guy claimed I got it wrong that neurons die (I argued that even if you live a billion years you die slowly many times over because all your cells incl. nervous cells will have to be replaced, meaning you will regularly - but never suddenly - become a new person; also: continuous learning, and information storage is physical, and our brain has very limited capacity so memories will change), immortal means they are immortal.

That got me thinking: Is it actually possible to have repair systems in each cell, or isn't it better to have a repair system on a much higher macro level and cell-level immortality is actually impossible? Background: The smaller the scale, the more events like quantum effects and Boltzman (energy) distribution (e.g. random atom movements, crystal structure defects, breaking bonds) dominate. Meaning small systems WILL break in unpredictable ways, so only large systems can live long and have reliable repair systems because the larger the system the less important those effects become.

Summary: It is much better (or even possible) to have big long-living systems than small ones, because the inevitable repair system cannot be too small because it will be subject to random events of the micro-world. An "immortal" human would have a body-level repair system that repairs by letting broken cells die (we have that already) and build a new one, instead of having a repair system on the cell-level that would make cells immortal (too unreliable, won't work).

Or in other words: The smaller the system the less likely a long life can be achieved.

Note that I'm asking about complex dynamic systems, not static objects or information. Like living organisms or (complicated) machines, and about their chance to "live long".

Comment: You are asking the question in the wrong forum. The correct place would be communications theory, where they analyze the error tolerance of information processing and transmitting systems. It can be shown, that one can construct efficient codes at any level of error tolerance, which basically takes the question out of the realm of physics. Tell the communications people what your error rate is, and they can tell you how to engineer a system that is tolerant to that error level to any desired reliability.

Comment: I don't think so. It is a physics question in the end. About quantum effects and energy distribution and how it plays out on micro vs. macro scale. I've a CS degree and I've just taken several courses in chemistry (last one: MIT 3.091 - Solid State Chemistry) and I think this belongs *here*. What you describe is different - where does size and the influence of those things I mentioned, much stronger in smaller systems, come in? This isn't about "information" but about the actual physical objects storing it. (continued)

Comment: Also: Information does not care whether I store it in the form of a protein (long carbon chain) or (with lots of redundancy) on a huge object - but the protein is subject to the described physical random effects and will break much (much!) more quickly than the much larger thing. So *where* it is stored matters.

Comment: You may not think so, but please look at the communications theory textbooks. You will find that those folks have done much more rigorous work on the question of how one can encode information on unreliable physical channels than physicists. This is simply not a topic for physics. Now, if you think that you know better all along than us, why do you even ask this question here?

Comment: This isn't about encoding information! Who cares if you manage to encode information eternally? This is about a living organism, a system! About processes, repair mechanisms (machines)? I'm not asking if you can store DNA (or whatever) eternally. If you can't do anything with the question, could you please just ignore it? Thanks.

Comment: So what do you think "you" are? A bunch of molecules? That's not "you", that's your body. I can keep your body in one piece for a million years by freezing it in liquid nitrogen. But that does not keep that electrical pattern in your brain intact that makes you "you". Again, this is not a physics topic.

Comment: See here, I'm instructed to ask in Physics":
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/which-stack-exchange-is-appropriate-for-information-theory-questions

Comment: I am not responsible for people who don't know better and please watch your language. I am not here to be insulted by people who don't have the ability to accept   answers that don't fit their predetermined minds.

Comment: Can we take this person offline, please? I am done here.

Comment: By the way, telling me it's the "wrong forum" without telling me where you think it would be better suited is just silly. There is no "IT" forum on stackexchange, and see the link to the other discussion - apparently other people don't think like you.